# Application deployement and network models

Tags: computer-networks, books, applications

I am a self-taught in computer science. I am interested on have a robust test book on which study the nut and bolt of application deployment.
I mean all the processes involved in getting new software up and running properly in a given network. (entry point, rest interfaces etc etc) I went through books of computer networking like Tanenbaum and Kurose but I don't know if these are good choice.
Should I focus on something else?
Many thanks

Comment: This seems off-topic on this site, which has a more theoretical bent.